# How to avoid CORS issue on 302 redirect after an ajax post call?

Tags: angular, ajax, oauth-2.0, http-status-code-302, hydra

I am trying to implement an oauth2 login flow using :

- Hydra oauth2 server
- Identity Provider
- The frontend application is using angular framework

Here is the first part of the flow (until I get the CORS issue) :
[image]

As long as I do a non Ajax form POST, 302 redirection goes well.
But angular framework does not come with nice solution to avoid ajax form. Tell me if i'm wrong.

What is the best solution between the following :

- do non ajax form in angular
- replace 302 by 200 with the redirectUrl in the response and let angular do the redirection
- allow cross origin on hydra
- any other solution ?

Comment: Add CORS via the proxy maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the following solution :

> replace 302 by 200 with the redirectUrl in the response and let angular do the redirection

and it works well.